# How to write log file for deb package installation?

Tags: deb, log, debian-installer

I have created a deb package and i need to write log files for my deb package at the time of installation. I can see some log files are created in this location '/var/log/'. But it does not contain the exact failure information if anything occurred during installation. So i need to get the complete log information for my deb package.

How to get this?

Comment: I'd be distinctly unhappy if a package I attempted to install crapped all over `/var/log` when it fails to install. If it failed to install, **it has no business making any more changes in the filesystem.**

Comment: 100% agree with muru. Messages need to be on-screen and nothing else.

Comment: Package can be installed through deb package installer(GDebi) also. In this case, we can trace the error through log files only.

Comment: @KathirSubramaniam irrelevant. No matter how the package is installed, **no** package has any business writing to log files when installing fails

Answer (score 1):

(If installing the .deb package from the terminal) The terminal "should" automatically print (echo) any errors that occur... You should be able to just look at the terminal and see all the errors.

Comment: Thanks @Haptenhappy. I can see error in terminal. But i need to write the errors in log files. Because package can be installed through terminal and through Package manager(GDebi). So it will be better if the error detail available in log files.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file > log.txt
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The last command needed as dpkg doesn't solve dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Misha. I tried your solution. I will execute some operations in postinst custom script. It returned an error and failed to install the package. But this error detail is not available in log file.